# Connect PC to Xbox One without wireless display

Tags: pc, xbox-one, streaming

I am trying to stream a PC game from a PC (obviously) to an Xbox One. The problem is that I have the PC connected to a router via cable so I can't use a wireless display.

Is there any other way that I can stream a PC game to an Xbox One?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to stream PC games to your TV? Or Xbox games to your PC Monitor? Why would you want to use an Xbox for the PC to stream to instead of just to the TV directly?–

Comment: @Rapitor Yes I am trying to stream from PC to Xbox. I cant stream to TV because my TV have no functionality for this. Basically on PC is running VR (oculus quest2) game and I want to see that game on TV while xbox is connected to TV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by your clarification comment and what you want to do. This isn't possible for the Xbox One to do (it's streaming capabilities is to stream from the console to other devices, not the other way around).

What you would need is a TV or Device capable of casting, like a Google ChromeCast. Once that is set up you will need to do the following:

1. Open the Oculus App on your phone.
2. Go to the devices section
3. Select your Quest2
4. Select the Cast option
5. Here you will be given choices to select the source and destination of the cast, select the chromecast(or whatever casting device you have chosen/setup). Make sure everything is on the same wi-fi network.
6. start and enjoy

Another option you can try, if you are so intent on using the xbox. The internet browser app could be a solution (i don't know how well this will work, if it all... but it's worth a shot)

1. On the xbox, open the internet app
2. go to oculus.com/casting
3. press the right menu button on your oculus controller
4. select sharing->cast
5. select computer and hit next, if you dont see the device, make sure everything is on the same wi-fi network. If they are and you just don't see it, then this idea is busted.
6. done

Comment: That's great idea to use Xbox browser I totally forget about it thank you :)

Comment: This is wrong. There is a free Wireless Display App from Microsoft on the XBox store which allows you to stream audio and video from a PC running Windows to XBox using the Wireless Display functionality in Windows.